# Migrating Google App Engine - Eclipse Java 8

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

Google App Engine no longer supports Java 8. I am using Eclipse and used it in combination with the Goolge App Engine tools. Testing and deploying was very simple. I am looking for a method how I can easily migrate my current code to Java 21 and still use Eclipse.

Is there are way to migrate a Java Eclipse project to Java 21 and keep the testing and deployment process simple?

Looking at the documentation I see a lot of frameworkes and tools like Maven and Spring. I am hesitant to use several new tools which might not work with my setup.

Is there an easy and simple way to keep making changes to my Java application under Eclipse or any other IDE? I am happy to change code and do the migration work I just don't want to learn 100 deployment steps and then figure out a change to Spring will not work with my setup.

Thank you

I tried to install Eclipse with new Google Cloud tools but I cannot figure out how to simply migrate my application.

Comment: The current (2024-03) version of Eclipse supports Java 21.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to keep using eclipse, but first, google app engine tools is no longer available. I have to use Maven to import most of my libraries:

[Maven New Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esfmv.png)

Set java8 to false and Use App Engine Api true:

[Maven Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W3Jp.png)

Then in the terminal, i suggest set the appengine-version to 2.0.24

[Appengine version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nso9X.png)